Unterschied zwischen 'vorab' und 'voraus'
Oft schreibe ich in E-Mails Danke im Voraus. Damit möchte ich mich für etwas bedanken, das die andere Person noch tun soll. Ich habe jedoch bemerkt, dass deutsche Muttersprachler vorab vorziehen, so wie in Ich danke Ihnen vorab für die Unterstützung. Soweit ich weiß, haben beide Ausdrücke in diesem Zusammenhang die gleiche Bedeutung.
Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wörtern?
Hat der eine Ausdruck eine andere Konnotation als der andere?

Vorab kann nur zeitlich verwendet werden, während voraus auch räumlich anwendbar ist.
Ich würde im angebebene Beispiel bei im Voraus bleiben, weil vorab außerdem bedeuten kann (vgl . Vorabversion), dass das Objekt unvollständig, noch nicht fertig überarbeitet ist, oder dass weitere dazugehörende Teile noch nachgeliefert werden, z.B.

Vorab sende ich einen Entwurf, das komplette Manuskript folgt nach Fertigstellung.


Mit Sicherheit ist "voraus" allgemeiner. Es kann ja allein schon zeitlich und räumlich (bei einer Bewegung) gedeutet werden. Etwas kommt vor etwas anderem, dh etwas kommt, und etwas anderes kommt nach.
"Vorab" ist rein zeitlich, nicht räumlich (zB: "er fährt voraus" aber nicht in derselben Bedeutung "er fährt vorab"). Ich habe außerdem den Eindruck, es hat eine spezielle Bedeutung wie "etwas kommt früher als es in der Hauptsache kommen sollte". Eine "Vorab-Information" ist eine Information, die eigentlich erst später hätte kommen sollen, und die auch weniger ist als die Hauptsache, die später kommen soll.
Beim Danken ist mir die Formulierung "ich danke im Voraus" geläufiger. Vielleicht soll mit "vorab" gesagt werden, dass das nicht das letzte Dankeswort sein wird?
